# Array memcpy more than 1000 times faster than vector stl::copy on on ideone?

Tags: c++, c++11

I posted the following cone on ideone under http://ideone.com/Hp9pL8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  constexpr size_t elems = 500000;
  {
    int array_source[elems];
    int array_destination[elems];
    iota(begin(array_source),end(array_source),0);
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    memcpy (array_destination, array_source, elems * sizeof(int));
    auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = stop - start;
    auto nanoseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);
    cout << "Duration of old style copy: " << nanoseconds.count() <<  " ns." << endl;
  }
  {
    vector<int> vector_source(elems);
    vector<int> vector_destination(elems);
    iota(begin(vector_source),end(vector_source),0);
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    copy(begin(vector_source), end(vector_source), begin(vector_destination));
    auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = stop - start;
    auto nanoseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);
    cout << "Duration of stl style copy: " << nanoseconds.count() <<  " ns." << endl;
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
Duration of old style copy: 280 ns.
Duration of stl style copy: 931438 ns.
```

I expected both approaches to produce nearly the same instructions on optimized build. Why is copying vector more than 1000 times slower. Is ideone not using any optimization at all?

Comment: If you want to measure `memcpy` against `std::copy`, use the same data types in both cases. You are using an automatic storage array for `memcpy` and an `std::vector` for `std::copy`, for no apparent reason.

Comment: In both cases the copy could be optimized out since it produces no output

Comment: It's unclear why the output ends in `ms.` when the code string contained `ns.`

Comment: Your output doesn't match the program written as-is ("ns" vs. "ms"), and this overflows the stack on my machine (because of the massive arrays you've allocated in the first block). I've tried this in Visual C++ 2013 with `elems = 100000` just so it can run and I get `0 ns` for both runs. Did you really run this on ideone?

Comment: @In silico Yes I did just follow the link

Comment: The first `memcpy` is completely optimized out as written. The compiler can easily prove that changes to `array_source` etc. are not externally observable and omit them. It's much harder for it to do so for dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/vrtUYw, the times are quite similar. But you need to think about optimizations too. When I run that locally with -02, the first loop gets optimized out.

Comment: @ T.C. How do you prevent this?

Comment: Okay, I've ran only the `vector`-based code with `elems = 500000` and I get `0 ns` with Visual C++ 2013 even in debug mode (optimizations disabled). Yes, I did step through the code and verified that it's actually allocating and copying things. I can't run the array-based code as-is without stack overflows. I think this is an issue with the compiler options and the execution environment, because I really can't reproduce this on my C++ setup.

Comment: @Insilico I believe VS2013's `<chrono>` is very broken. Its `high_resolution_clock` has about ~1 million ns resolution.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, I see. Let me re-run this with `QueryPerformanceCounter` and see if I can reproduce it this time.

Comment: Okay, now it makes more sense, but the timings I get are basically the same for both cases. I did not observe orders-of-magnitude difference in performance like the OP did. (Although I did lower `elems` to 100000 just so I can run the array code.) In any case, it's certainly have to do with the compiler optimization options.

Comment: @Insilico: I know for a fact that MSVC's stdlib at least lowers `std::copy` to a `memcpy` for known built-in types, and maybe for PODs in general.

Comment: @Xeo: I can confirm that Visual C++ 2013's implementation of `std::copy` eventually calls `memmove` for PODs after stepping through the OP's code. Interestingly I can reproduce this in release mode (optimizations on), and that's only because the optimizer basically got rid of the entire array-based code. So the OP isn't even testing the same things.

Comment: The reason gcc can't optimize the second version is that it does not consider operator new and delete as anything magic but as regular function calls. If you inline them so the compiler can see malloc and free (known magic), it is more likely to optimize that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a matter of optimization. You should use something in the `destination_array`. I patched your code as

```
memcpy (array_destination, array_source, elems * sizeof(int));
unsigned ix = getpid () % elems;
cout << "ix#" << ix << " @" << array_destination [ix] << endl;
auto stop = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = stop - start;
auto nanoseconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(duration);
```

<sup>Of course I also added the appropriate `#include`...</sup>

and got more reasonable timings (which indeed also measure the time for IO):

```
ix#4640 @4640
Duration of old style copy: 1925353 ns.
Duration of stl style copy: 910400 ns.
```

The compiler was right to optimize your code. The `array_destination` was not really used.

Of course you could move the output out of the timing. I did that on my own machine (I'm not very familiar with ideone), and got:

```
Duration of old style copy: 675192 ns.
Duration of stl style copy: 228392 ns.
ix#1877 x=1877
```

BTW, one could dream of a very clever optimizer which won't even construct neither `array_source` nor `array_destination` and would optimize the output line as

```
 cout << "ix#" << ix << " @" << ix << endl;
```

Since one could prove that for all index `i` we have `array_destination[i] == i` but compilers are not yet clever enough for that.

Comment: This is useless, since you are now timing the I/O as well.

Comment: I modified the original program to use heap allocated arrays instead of stack based arrays (in the first pass) and the same happen (the optimisation does not happen).

Comment: You only need to `cout << array_destination[0]` after the memcpy (after the stop) and the optimisation will not happen.